# Show that a countable compact set is removable.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

A compact set $E \subset \mathbb{C}$ is removable if there is no nonconstant and bounded analytic function in $\mathbb{C} \setminus E$. I can show that any finite set is removable. How do I apply the Baire Category Theorem to show that it is also true for countable compact sets?

Comment: See the remark after lemma 2.6 here: https://math.hawaii.edu/~myounsi/Removable.pdf

Comment: @ Reveillark, Thanks for providing the article. I read it and understand the proof in the remark. It uses mainly Lemma 2.6 depending on Lemmas 2.4 and 2.5. I think that they are quite technical and I guess that there is an elementary way to prove the same result, but I cannot figure it out.